# How do I create a page template to display a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am wanting to create a page template file to display posts from a custom content type. actually I have 3 different type of post type 'books', 'author' and news.
here is my problem these 3 post type have different template and I want to show each of theme in separate pages, first question should I call these post type in a page.php or in single.php? I already know that single.php using for dynamic content and page.php use for static one, what should I create for showing content of these post type?
here is an example:
I creat page-author.php file to showing author post type
here is my code

```
<?php /* Template Name: author-page-theme */ 
    get_header(); ?>
<div class="head-style col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="title-pack col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <span class="line visible-sm-block"></span>
        <span class="visible-sm-block tittle-style"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row writer-crit">
        <div class="writer-crit-box col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-12">
                <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Author', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ); 
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                    <a class="writer-link col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" href="<?php post_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="writer-row1 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 image-right">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 pull-right writer-content">
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <?php if ( get_field('auth-trans') ) { 
                                    echo '<h4>'.get_field('auth-trans').'</h4>';} ?>    
                                <?php if ( get_field('writer-bio') ) { 
                                    echo '<p>'.get_field('writer-bio').'</p>';} ?>

                                <span>...</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>                                              
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>
    </div>  
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

but it doesn't work. it shows just index page template not what I create for this page.
 Any suggestions on how to make this post appear ?
I completely new to WordPress and this is my first project so I really need help.

Comment: @Prabin Parajuli can u help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a page from admin and choose the template 'author-page-theme' from the dropdown box that says 'page template'. To show that on frontend, please go to appearance -> menus. then choose the corresponding menu. then drag the newly created page to the selected menu.

Comment: I did it before but it doesn't work. I thought because it's dynamic and shouldn't show it with page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(

    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => '',
    'category_name'    => '',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'Author',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'author'       => '',
    'author_name'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
);

$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```

then `var_dump($posts_array);`

Also, please check that `post_type` you entered is correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can go through custom post type template which is described here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates